# Sum elements in a list containing functions

Tags: r

I'm computing `ft` for values of `k`, and then storing them in the list `funcList`. Now I want to store `Xt` as a function of `t` as the sum of all elements in `funclist`. This is what I've done:

```
n = 100
funcList = list()

ft = function(t) {(abs(t) <= 1)*(1-(t)^2)+(abs(t) > 1)*(0)}

for (k in 1:100){
  funcList[[k]] = ft(t+k/n)*rnorm(100,0,1)
}

Xt = rowSums(sapply(funcList, ?)
```

However, I'm not sure at all how I should express `Xt` here and how to use the functions `rowSums()` and `sapply()`.

Answer (score 0):

Realy not sure what you try to do.
Your code throws an error, since in your for loop there is no value defined for t. 
Are you tring to do something like this:

```
n = 100
funcList = list(100)

ft = function(t) {(abs(t) <= 1)*(1-(t)^2)+(abs(t) > 1)*(0)}

for (k in 1:100){
  funcList[[k]] = function(t) {ft(t+k/n)*rnorm(100,0,1)}
}
```

for a fixed t (say t = -1) you can than do :

```
result <- sapply(funcList,function(ft_i)ft_i(-1))
```

and afterwards call rowSums

```
result2 <- rowSums(result)
```

but to be honest, that sounds like a relay complicated thing to do....

Comment: Well, as I said, I want to compute ft for certain k then place the result in a list and them make a large function consisting of the sum of all these. Hope this is clear. Yes it's quite complicated, this is a part of a huge stochastic process simulation I'm doing. I will try what you have suggested, thank you.

Comment: Why is my result a matrix? How do I interpret the columns and rows here? How can I make result to be only a vector?

Comment: I did not mean complicated in a sense that what you try to do is complicated, but to do this by creating a list of functions is not necessary in my eyes:'ftk <- function(t,k,n) ft(t+k/n)*rnorm(n,0,1)
ftk_fix <- function(k) ftk(-1,k,100)
result <- sapply(1:100,ftk_fix)'

Comment: you have a list of 100 functions. For a given value t each of this functions returns a vector of size 100 (the return value of ft multiplied by 100 random numbers). As a result you end up with 100 times 100 values. sapply simplifes that into a  matrix of that size... If you want to avid this use lapply